# Can't read Modbus holding register because ModbusMaster for arduino is lack of documentation

Tags: arduino, embedded, iot, modbus, rs485

### The Problem:

Hi, First of all, i am no expert at **C++**.

I seem can't find any of the guide(or documentation) of modbusMaster especially for [this](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster) particular library. Which explains all the class method uses.

I use this library because it supports **stream class**. not like official library or others. Therefore, i can use **softwareSerial** to add more serial for rs485.

I am using **Arduino pro mini**, that's why i need software serial. And this **Max485 module**:

[image]

I am very sure everything is connected properly, thus my aim is to read coil from a Chinese brand ultrasonic level meter which the guide says:

[image]

Here's the program what i am trying to do:

```cpp
#include <ModbusMaster.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*!
  We're using a MAX485-compatible RS485 Transceiver.
  Rx/Tx is hooked up to the hardware serial port at 'Serial'.
  The Data Enable and Receiver Enable pins are hooked up as follows:
*/
#define MAX485_DE      9
#define MAX485_RE_NEG  8
//for software serial
#define RO_RX 7
#define DI_TX 6


// instantiate ModbusMaster object
ModbusMaster node;
// RX, TX on softser
SoftwareSerial mySerial(RO_RX, DI_TX); 

void preTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 1);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 1);
}

void postTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
  // Init in receive mode
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);

  // for serial monitoring on PC
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Modbus communication runs at 9600 baud
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  // Modbus slave ID 1 and pass the software serial
  node.begin(1, mySerial);
  // Callbacks allow us to configure the RS485 transceiver correctly
  node.preTransmission(preTransmission);
  node.postTransmission(postTransmission);
  Serial.println("init done...");
}



void loop()
{
// now, i'm kinda lost here..

  delay(100);
  Serial.println("loop end.");
}
```

I am confused with most of the *class method* without a proper explanation.

```cpp
modbusObj.readWriteMultipleRegisters();
modbusObj.writeSingleRegister();
modbusObj.setTransmitBuffer();
modbusObj.readCoils();
modbusObj.writeMultipleRegisters();
modbusObj.readHoldingRegisters();
// etc..
```

They had no documentation. Well, Some method names are self explanatory but not about the arguments.I am trying just to read the holding register.

### TL;DR:

I want to read the level meter's distance data, but the library doesn't provide a proper documentation.

### Nb:

- nothing wrong with the ultrasonic device, tested in PC to read holding register with some modbus tool and hooked up to **rs485 to usb** and working!
- this question intended in stack overflow rather than [stack-electrical-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) because I am mainly asking about the code.
- I've been discussing it with someone in a local facebook forum that said he's successfully utilizing the lib alongside soft-serial and pro-mini.

Comment: this library? https://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoModbus/ArduinoModbus

Comment: you should first understand Modbus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus

Comment: never mind, i've found the lib already. now it's working